# How to handle selection event with a wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently on a C# WPF project and I display images in several rows (the blue heads)

[image]

The problem is that I can't select any of this items, I am using a MVVM pattern so the code behind must be as light as possible and I have to do eveything I can in the xaml file.

So I would like to be able to select images by clicking on them, I've tried to use event like "IsMouseOver" but I was only able to change the whole wrappanel and not single items.

Here is the code I use:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Color="#252525" />
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <ItemsControl Background="Transparent" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Context:Session.CurrentSession}, Path=CurrentProject.Models}">
            <ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteModel3DCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>
                </ContextMenu>                    
            </ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectModel3DCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/McKineap;component/Resources/Images/logo-mckineap.png" Height="100"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>   
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

I will take any suggestions you could have about the proper way to define a select event in my wrappanel, thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to do the same way but with a ListBox instead of a ListView and it works for me.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Color="#252525" />
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <ListBox Name="ModelsListBox" Background="Transparent" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" BorderBrush="Transparent" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Context:Session.CurrentSession}, Path=CurrentProject.Models}">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteModel3DCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectModel3DCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="/McKineap;component/Resources/Images/logo-mckineap.png"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="55" Width="50"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding NameWithoutExtension}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 6):

`ItemsControl` items wasn't meant to be selectable, that's why selection events and selection features are missing, more specifically `ItemsControl` doesn't inherit from `Selector` class which allow that, on the other hand [`ListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) do.

Change the `ItemsControl` to a `ListView` and you should be able to implement selection:

```
 <ListView SelectionMode="Single" Background="Transparent" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" BorderBrush="Transparent"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```

**Edit**
don't forget to disable the HorizontalScrollBar in the `ListView` in-order for the `WrapPanel` to work

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color="#252525" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <ListView SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" BorderBrush="Transparent"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteModel3DCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectModel3DCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="refresh.png" Height="100"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your post helped me a lot to understand how this work but nothing is displayed (I corrected the image path) I think the error could come from the ItemPanelTemplate but I'm not sure about it